# Apparent contradiction between First and Second Laws of Thermodynamics

Tags: thermodynamics, big-bang

How is the Second Law of Thermodynamics not either false or incompatible with the First Law of Thermodynamics?

In practice, the Second Law entails that, given an infinite amount of time, there should be virtually no useful energy in the cosmos. 
There is, of course, lots of useful energy; thus, either the First Law was, at some point, broken (new energy was created) or the Second Law is simply incorrect and there is or was an 'uphill flow' of energy.

The common response I've gotten from lay-persons is that the Second Law applies within the context of time, but, as space-time had a beginning (i.e., the Big Bang), neither the First nor the Second Law ever had to be violated, per se.

This never satisfied me: As far as I am aware, there is no direct evidence to suggest that space-time began at the Big Bang. Instead, all the evidence that we have points to the fact that the universe was once very dense, but not necessarily to some absolute beginning.

Clearly, scientists cleverer than me have been working on this for years; so I'm sure there's a real answer. Can you give me some input?

Comment: What is your definition of the term "useful energy?"

Comment: I mean, Energy that is capable of doing work, in the Physical sense.

Comment: Or, perhaps, it could be said like this: In practice, the Second Law entails that, given an infinite amount of time, the Cosmos should be in a state of near-absolute equilibrium (leaving aside QM).

Comment: Re *As far as I am aware, there is no direct evidence to suggest that space-time began at the Big Bang*: To the contrary! Most cosmologists are of the opinion that the Big Bang was when time started. Asking what happened before the Big Bang is a non sequitur from this point of view.

Comment: @DavidHammen, I don't think that you're correct: Lawrence Krauss, for instance, has said on multiple occasions that while he suspects that the Big Bang was the beginning of the universe, there is no hard evidence either way. I think there isn't really a consensus: There are three versions of the Big Bang and many fringe-y Hypotheses, but no real Theories. You could say that the absolute beginning can be deduced from GR, but GR breaks down at the Big Bang; so no one knows.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the apparent conflict between the First and Second laws of thermodynamics.  For example, do you mean to say that time may go infinitely far back such that we should see only entropy and not free energy by now, such that the existence of free energy seems like a contradiction?  Or if not that, what's the apparent contradiction that you're asking about?

Comment: @Nat, That's pretty much exactly what I'm talking about. [The first option.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three points to answer:

1. Even without discussing the Big Bang, for which there is plenty of evidence, it is just as possible that time had a beginning as that it hadn't. So your argument only applies in the case that the universe has existed for an infinite amount of time, and with all the same physical laws for that infinite time. Recognize that this is quite a large assumption and not at all entailed in the usual formulation of physics.
2. The "laws" of thermodynamics hold effectively, for larger time-scales and larger systems, especially the second one. There are known cases where entropy decreases for a short time in a small system. In classical mechanics, we also have the Poincare recurrence theorem that hints at the possibility that the rise in entropy cannot hold at all time scales and must come to an end somewhen (but this is not totally clear, either.)
   So, in a nutshell, laws of thermodynamics don't have the same fundamental status as other laws of physics like Maxwell's laws, Schrödinger's equation and so on. So we should not wonder to much if we get alleged contradictions when applying them to the whole, maybe infinite history, of the universe.
3. The way you connect the first and second law is maybe also problemativ since at first sight, they are both about different physical entities: the first about energy, and the second about entropy. The connection that entropy measures somehow how much "useful energy" there is is rather loose.

Comment: Thank you for the good response! I never rejected the Big Bang; I don't know why people seem to kinda imply that I do, LOL. Anyway, this really was a good answer: What you're saying is that these Laws may, in some sense, break down eventually?

Also a Note: I'm not connecting entropy to a lack of useful energy in some absolute sense: I'm just saying that a state of equilibrium, i.e., a near-absence of useful energy is a logical Consequence of the Law.

Answer (score 1):

DISCLAIMER: this answer does not take into account inflationary cosmology or the accelerating expansion of the universe. However, I believe it still answers the heart of the question.

The important part is "given an infinite amount of time." The universe has only existed for a finite amount of time, so entropy is not yet maximized.

This universal increase of entropy happens *very slowly*, as the universe is very large and, for the most part, pretty highly ordered (gravity tends to clump things into galaxies, which are tiny on a cosmological scale, and close encounters between galaxies that would allow material to "mix" are pretty rare). At some point in the (very, very, very, *very*) far future, however, some theories predict that the entropy of the universe eventually will increase high enough that energy will be essentially uniformly distributed, entropy will be maximized, and no free energy will remain. This point in time, colloquially called the "heat death of the universe," is predicted (depending on the cosmological model) to be at least $10^{100}$ years away, when the last supermassive black holes evaporate and stop emitting Hawking radiation. Considering that the current age of the universe is something like $10^{10}$ years, that's quite a long way away.

EDIT:

We know that the laws of thermodynamics work; we've tested them in various situations thousands of times. We also know that free energy exists; if it didn't, we wouldn't exist. There are two different assumptions that one might make if one considers how the laws of thermodynamics apply to the universe at large:

1) We assume conservation of energy. Under this assumption, a universe existing for an infinite amount of time will have no free energy. Since we manifestly observe the existence of free energy, the universe must have only existed for a finite amount of time.

2) We assume an eternal universe. Under this assumption, if energy were conserved, free energy would not exist. Therefore, the existence of free energy leads us to conclude that the conservation of energy is violated.

There is lots of evidence that seems to support option 1 (the universe's expansion, the existence of the Cosmic Microwave Background, the relative abundance of light nuclei in stars, the fact that distant, early galaxies look very different than nearby, modern galaxies, etc.), even if none of it convinces you that it actually happened.

In contrast, there is no known evidence that seems to support option 2. The conservation of energy has held in every single experiment we've ever done. The last time it was doubted was when the beta decay spectrum was finally measured, back when we thought the reaction was simply $n\to p+e^-$. The beta decay spectrum didn't at all match what was predicted by the reaction kinematics, so there were a substantial number of people who took this as evidence that conservation of energy was violated in this reaction. But Fermi proposed the existence of another particle, which we now call the *neutrino*, which carried away the extra energy and made the reaction $n\to p+e^-+\overline{\nu}$. We were able to decide between these two hypotheses when the neutrino was directly detected a few decades later, proving that energy was conserved.

Based on the balance of evidence, the consensus is that option 2 has essentially been ruled out. There might be a theory that violates conservation of energy, upholds an eternal universe, and explains all known physical results, but no such theory currently exists, and if one were to exist, it would likely have to be so convoluted that Occam's razor would heavily favor the one we have now.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'm very grateful that you took the time! However, I feel that you may have missed part of my post:
As far as I am aware, there is no direct evidence to suggest that space-time began at the Big Bang. Instead, all the evidence that we have points to the fact that the universe was once very dense, but not necessarily to some absolute beginning [not to a beginning of space-time]. Thus, I can't see a way out?!

Comment: PS; it should be pointed out that I'm not endorsing some crackpot idea about what happened 'before' the Big Bang. I'm just saying, as far as I am aware, there is the fact of the Big Bang on the one hand (i.e., the universe was once very dense) and on the other hand there are a number of as yet unproven models of what actually happened. My issue is that I see no real reason to think that space-time began.

Comment: @QuestionszAsked See edit.

Comment: @QuestionszAsked wrote  *it should be pointed out that I'm not endorsing some crackpot idea about what happened 'before' the Big Bang.*  Well, for example, Roger Penrose is not considered a crackpot but he and others seriously consider questions such as this in search for some explanation of the unreasonably low entropy of the 'initial' condition.  See, for example, [Conformal cyclic cosmology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_cyclic_cosmology)

Comment: probably_someone, thank you for the update. However, I think that you did misunderstand me; I accept the Big Bang and all the evidence that you presented. My issue is with the idea that the Cosmos had a beginning not that the Big Bang took place—the Big Bang is a Scientific fact—the beginning of everything is still if I am correct, Hypothetical. In other words, I don't think there is an accepted set explanation of the Big Bang.

Now, I would take the conservation of energy to be an axiom in the argument, so what I'm really asking about is the Second Law.

Comment: probably_someone, also, I think that you missed a third possibility:

3) The eternal universe and the Conservation Law But no Second Law i.e., uphill flow.

I'm not saying this is true, I suspect it isn't, I'm just wondering how to think about it if you don't regard the Big Bang as a beginning of time/space.

Comment: @QuestionszAsked The Second Law is essentially a pure consequence of statistics. It has been tested thousands of times and has not been seen to ever be violated. Therefore, taking the conservation of energy as an axiom, and taking into account the experimental validation of the Second Law, one must conclude that the universe has a beginning (or else it existed for infinite time frozen in a state with zero entropy increase and then arbitrarily decided a finite amount of time ago to start increasing its entropy, but observationally these two should be indistinguishable).

Comment: @QuestionszAsked If there were no Second Law, then there would be no arrow of time in the first place. It would take quite a convoluted set of additional assumptions to get that to agree with our universe.

Comment: @probably_someone, Thank you! That was the best answer I've gotten so far. I can already perceive some interesting possibilities. Do you have any reading recommendations on the statistical foundations of the Second Law? Thank you for taking the time.

Comment: Also, a Note: Wasn't there a very slight amount of entropy at the Big Bang?

Comment: @QuestionszAsked The resource request might receive more attention as a separate question. And I don't know whether the value of the entropy at the Big Bang has been determined, but it makes no difference to the above arguments either way.